# Using malloc to return an int array in a function

Tags: c, malloc, twos-complement

I'm writing a C program that takes in a num (decimal, hex, or octal) and converts it into two's complement binary form.

The algorithm should be right since I had use it elsewhere before but I am confused on how to return the array of int's of 0's and 1's.

My understanding is I have to use malloc to allocate the memory space for this new array but I'm not sure how to do it syntax-wise.

This is what I have so far:

```
char *itob (int num, int size) {
        int binary[size];
        binary[size] = (int *)malloc(size);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                binary[i] = 0;
        }
        int decimal = num;
        int counter = 0;

        if (decimal > -32768 && decimal < 32767) {
                if (decimal < 0) {
                        decimal = 65536 + decimal;
                }
                while (decimal>0) {
                        binary[counter] = decimal%2;
                        decimal = decimal/2;
                        counter++;
                }
        }

        return binary;
}
```

The parameter `num` is the number to convert and `size` is the number of bits I want to print.

Comment: 1) Never cast the malloc result in C. The compiler does it for you. This also helps you make it right: 2) The malloc result is a pointer assign it to a pointer variable: `int *binary = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);` 3) Make you return type the same as your `binary` variable type.

Comment: I tried `int *binary = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);` and I get the error `variable-sized object may not be initialized`?

Comment: Remove the line `int binary[size];`

Comment: Hmm..I did that

Comment: Remove line 'binary[size] = (int *)malloc(size);'. Variable binary has automatic storage

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allocate and return an array of `int` variables, you need your function to return an `int*` value (not `char*`); then, inside that function simply allocate a local `int*` pointer and return that, when you've calculated and assigned its elements.

Note that the size of the memory block to be allocate should be the number of elements (the `size` argument, in your case) *multiplied by the size of each element* (which will be `sizeof(int)`, for your code).

You can access the elements in the allocated data using the `[]` (index) operator on the returned pointer, just as though that were an array.

```c
int* itob(int num, int size) // Returns an int array, not a char array
{
//  int binary[size];
//  binary[size] = (int*)malloc(size);
    int* binary = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); // Note: Don't cast the "malloc" return!
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        binary[i] = 0;
    }
    int decimal = num;
    int counter = size - 1; // Your code will return the digits in reverse order!

    if (decimal > -32768 && decimal < 32767) {
        if (decimal < 0) {
            decimal = 65536 + decimal;
        }
        while (decimal > 0) {
            binary[counter] = decimal % 2;
            decimal = decimal / 2;
            counter--; // See the comment on the initialization of "counter"
        }
    }

    return binary;
}
```

Don't forget to release the allocated memory (in the calling module) by calling `free()` on the pointer returned by `itob` (after you've finished working with it).

On the casting (or not) of the `malloc` return (in C), see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073).

Comment: Wow thank you! I was wondering, how would I change the code if I were to want it to return char? I just realized my header file says to return a char array, but I'm not sure how that would be possible because I am doing integer calculations? Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Sarah Read point 2) of my comment. The return type must match the type of the variable `binary`. If you need that return type, change `binary`s type.

Comment: @Sarah Converting to a `char` array is simple: Basically, you just need to change the assignment line from `binary[counter] = decimal % 2;` to `binary[counter] = (char)((decimal % 2)  + '0');` Also, `sizeof(int)` (in `malloc`) will then be `sizeof(char)` - which is `1` by definition.

Comment: Cool! Can I ask why I need to do + '0'?

Comment: The characters representing the digits, '0' thru '9' have values that are *not* 0 thru 9 - though they are, by definition, contiguous. In ASCII (the most common system used), the '0' character has a value of 48 and '9' has 57. Using the `'0'` format makes your code work on non-ASCII systems, as well.

Comment: Also, I keep getting an error saying `variable-sized object may not be initialized` for `char *binary[size] = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);`. As @harper said I deleted any other initializations of the array but I still get this error..

Comment: @Sarah Look at my code carefully. There is no `[size]` in the `int* binary = malloc(...` line. You want a ***single*** pointer, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I missed that, it's a bit early in the morning for me :( Thank you so much! I understand now

Comment: Follow up question, I hope that's okay, for some reason nothing is printing as the result of this code. I'm testing with `itob('A', 8)` but it doesn't print anything. I keep thinking it's because my code is only for decimals, but I'm not sure how I'd change it to detect if it's hex, octal, etc..

Comment: Why are you passing a character literal? Your function takes an `int` first argument. But you should make a new question, perhaps, for using different bases (hex or octal).

Comment: @sarah: please keep in mind, this is not a tutorial site. If you need help learning C, please consider reading a(n) (e)book or follow a good online tutorial. There might also be courses at your local university/college or similar institute, depending on your location. Expecially C is not a good language to learn by trial&error because of the nature of undefined behaviour (please look it up). There is a Q&A on SO recommending C books, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
int binary[size];
    binary[size] = (int *)malloc(size);
```

this allocates `size` bytes, which will not work for you.  Suggest:

```
int *binary = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
if( ! binary )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

no casting of the returned value from `malloc()` because in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer  AND `binary[size]` is an array, not a pointer. I.E. the cast, besides being unneeded, is wrong